# Failed to update autoscale configuration

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm struggling with this for days and I can't find any resources/solutions for my problem. I want to autoscale my website api to request count and I always get this error "Failed to update autoscale configuration" when I try to save it. Mind you, I have 1 resource group and in this group they are 3 web apps and 1 sql server in it. I can see that I can scale only on App service plan. Why is that? Where can I find more descriptive error?

[image]

Comment: You can only scale the plan because that contains the instances where the apps in the plan live. You can't set instance counts per app, it has to be done on plan level. As for the error, I really have no idea. What tier is your App Service Plan? Auto-scale requires Standard at least.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm on Standard plan. Also, I managed to scale my plan based on Avg(CPU) metric. This is the only metric that Azure portal allowed me to save. Could it be, that this is happening to me because I have mixed types in my resource group?

Answer (score 1):

There might have some unexpected data in the original auto scale setting. I suggest you delete the original setting before adding a new one.

To only way I found currently to delete an autoscale setting is using [Azure Monitor REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931954.aspx). Here is the URL format and the method to send this request should be Delete.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/microsoft.insights/autoscaleSettings/{autoscale-setting-name}?api-version={api-version}
```

You could get the subscription id and resource group name from Azure portal. You could the autoscale setting name from the scale out panel of your Web App. The api version could be 2015-04-01.

[image]

In the request header, you also need to provide the Authorization Bearer token.

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJK.....V1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6
```

An easy way to get Bearer token is that open IE/Edge debug tool by clicking F12. When you use any Azure feature from Azure portal, you could find the token in the Network -> Header panel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  It allowed me to do a GET, update the content (JSON) and then do a PUT in order to fix the bad references.